# How to avoid 403 problem using BeautifulSoup and headers?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am using the combination of **request** and **beautifulsoup** to develop a web-scraping program in python. 
Unfortunately, I got 403 problem (even using **header**).
Here my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

headers_m = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
sapo_m = "https://www.idealista.it/vendita-case/milano-milano/"

response_m = get(sapo_m, headers=headers_m)
```

Comment: is this ur full code?

Comment: Obviously not, it' s just the part trying to "enter" in the web-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not general python question. The site blocks such straightforward attempts of **scraping**, you need to find a set of headers (specific for this site) that will pass validation.

Regards,

Comment: Is there a way to find/look for a specific set of headers?

Comment: I just tried a following way and it worked:  - open the site in browser (I am using chromium)  - open the 'inspect' view (it might be also called 'developer')  - go to Network tab  - select the 'request headers' that your browser sent to the site

Comment: the code:
````headers_m={
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'
}
````

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Chrome` as `User-Agent`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://...", headers={"User-Agent": "Chrome"}).content, 'html.parser')
```